# Retaining check box values after the form is submitted in PHP

Tags: php

But when the form is submitted it does not retain the check boxes selected. For instance If I select and checked two check boxes how do i keep them checked even after the form is submitted? Thanks.

below is what i have.

```
<form method='post' action=''>
<?php
$SQLbrands="SELECT * FROM brands";
            $runBrands=mysqli_query($db, $SQLbrands) or die ("SQL Error");
            $noRow=mysqli_num_rows($runBrands);
            $brndTable = "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1' id='brndTable1' class='brndTable1'>";
            $brndTable .= "<thead><tr><th class='brT11'>Brand Name</th><th class='brT21'>Variant</th><th class='brT31'>SKU</th><th class='brT41'></th></tr></thead>";
            $brndTable .= "<tbody>";
            while ($reK = mysqli_fetch_array($runBrands))
            {
                $wec = $reK['id']; $wec2 = $reK['bvariant']; $wec3 = $reK['bsku'];
                $brndTable .= "<tbody class='colormine'><tr>";
                $brndTable .= "<td class='brT1'>".$reK["bname"]."</td>";
                $brndTable .= "<td class='brT2'>".$reK["bvariant"]."</td>";
                $brndTable .= "<td class='brT3'>".$reK["bsku"]."</td>";
                $brndTable .= "<td class='brT4'><input type='checkbox' name='checkedMe[]' value='$wec' /></td>";
                $brndTable .= "</tr>";
            }
            $brndTable .= "</tbody>";
            $brndTable .= "</table>";


            echo $brndTable;
?>
<input type="submit" name="sendone" id="sendone" value="OneClick">
</form>
```

Comment: you' need to include the `checked="checked"` attribute when you rebuild the form after submission...

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the settings of these checkbox values on your server (perhaps in your database).  Then, next time your PHP script presents this form to your users, your PHP script should query this information, and write the `checked` attribute to check any checkboxes that should be checked.

Comment: Sorry for asking this but will you be able to give me an example according to my scenario? thanks

Comment: <? 
  // PHP code to query databse to see if checkbox1 should be
  // checked.  
  // if so, $c=1, if not, $c=0
?>

<input type=checkbox name=checkbox1 id=checkbox1 value=1
<?if($c) { print 'checked'; } ?>
>